# AngularJS how to create multi-dimensional object based on user input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I am extending an existing web application built using AngularJS, NodeJS, Sails and Mongo.

The app allows users to order food.

I am creating a simple page with hard-coded menu items.

I need to submit this data to the database. My plan is to first create a Javascript object and pass it to a method that writes the object to the database.

I am currently using ng-bind to capture the user input data and add it to the boxlunchOrder object.

Question: I want to populate the "sandwiches" array with the name of the sandwich and the quantity that the user wants to order.

**Current output:**

```
//boxlunchOrder object
{"sandwiches":[],"sandwiches_type":"wrap","sandwiches_total_qty":8}
```

**Desired output:**

```
//boxlunchOrder object
{"sandwiches":[
  "Chicken Salad" : 2,
  "Grilled Chicken Breast" : 3,
  "Grilled Vegetables Provolone" : 1,
  "Ham and Swiss Cheese" : 1,
  "Roast Beef" : 3
],
"sandwiches_type":"wrap",
"sandwiches_total_qty":10}
```

**Update 2:**

I may have been over-thinking this with trying to use two different objects, one to populate the initial sandwich options and another to populate the user's order.

Instead, I updated the code to just use the same object, initialize it in the controller with the data structure that is required, and then enable the user to update the object by entering values into the form with ng-bind on the elements.

https://plnkr.co/edit/0xg6jrwx9F4fOaim0Uxy?p=preview

I am curious if this is "best practice". I want to learn how to do this the correct way.

Comment: Your desired "format" is not valid JavaScript. You could do `{"Boxlunch Order": { "total_qty": 20, ... } }`. From what I can tell, you want an array of sandwiches. So make the `boxlunchOrder.sandwiches` property an array and use something like `ng-repeat` to write out your HTML.

Comment: based on your code, your putting total_qty inside the boxlunchOrder.sandwiches object. in your boxlunchOrder object, sandwiches and total_qty should be on the same level. the data in your sandwiches should be an array. i think it's better if you re-create your issue on plnkr so we can easily help you.

Comment: Thank you! I made a plunker for reference. I got slightly further with structuring my object properly, yet I still need to figure out how to create the array of objects to store the sandwich names and quantities that the user selects. I'm (obviously) new to AngularJS, so I've also been looking around for examples on "best practices" on how to achieve this requirement.